# batch file to automatically connect to vpn connection

Tags: batch-file, vpn

I need some help with batch file. I am using windows 7.
I need a batch file to:

1. Open VPN Client on my PC, path is
   ("C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\vpngui.exe)
2. There are 5 VPNs in the list. Connect to vpn name (AA_VPN) using my username and password

A window pop ups when I connect - that is 'continue or discontinue'
3. The process should press 'continue' button or spacebar key (all works)

4. And then the batch file should close itself.

Thanks.

Comment: `vpngui.exe -c -user username -pwd password  "AA_VPN"`

Comment: Thanks - I always get the error that 'windows could not find connect.

Comment: This is what I am using -    start "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\vpngui.exe" connect AA_VPN user xx pwd xx

Comment: Its `-c` for me on my version, not `connect` see `vpngui.exe /?` for options

Comment: hi - thanks, with -c i have been able to do the half bit. The batch files now opens the vpn client exe file - chooses the AA VPN, then my username / password window prompts. The process stops there. If does not put my username and password.. Dont know what could the issue now..

Comment: the command was - "C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\vpngui.exe" -c -user xx -pwd xxx "AA_VPN"

Answer (score 0):

From [documentation](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/security/vpn_client/cisco_vpn_client/vpn_client500_501/administration/5vcA.pdf):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Cisco Systems\VPN Client\vpnclient" connect AA_VPN user <yourUser> pwd <yourPassword>
```